# How to use AJV in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, ajv

I am trying to use AJV in a browser. I am getting module not found error. Is there a working example of AJV in a browser?

Here is the code I am using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/8.6.1/ajv7.min.js"></script>
<script>
  ;(function () {
    const Ajv = window.ajv7
    const ajv = new Ajv()
  })()
</script>
```

Comment: That's weird. It works if you downgrade to 8.1.0. I'm guessing there's a packaging issue somewhere.

Comment: @customcommander Thanks for the answer. Somehow I can't get it running even with 8.1.0. Could you share the code that worked please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I get the same error as you did except when I use 8.1.0. It could just be a temporary issue in packaging or delivery.

Here's how you'd use Ajv in a browser:

```js
const ajv = new window.ajv7();
const isAnswer = ajv.compile({"const": 42});
console.log(`
isAnswer(40)? ${isAnswer(40)}
isAnswer(42)? ${isAnswer(42)}
`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/8.1.0/ajv7.bundle.js" integrity="sha512-PuzkO+wOBh6m/Jux4nXgl2ItRzed77lFDidDX500DUNlvuzr4OrXtsFhN4q0CCxPoXjTFfiw1z4FmED9J/MMdQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

**Addendum**

I went through the issues on the repo site and somebody reported the same issue. See https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1744

Comment: Do you have an update for JSON schema draft 2020-12?  Thanks!